# Collapse multi-line records into single CSV lines containing the "value" parts only

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have data with multi-line records which looks like this:

```
Name>Ami  
Admin>2  
Oper>1  
Name>Sum  
Admin>3  
Total>2  
Name>Tar  
Admin>1  
Oper>2
```

Now I want to collapse these records into single CSV lines that should only contain the "value" parts of the record elements `Name`, `Admin` and `Oper`. For the example, the final output should look like this:

```
Ami,2,1  
Sum,3,
Tar,1,2
```

I am able to get the output from `paste - - - -d,` but I don't want to use this as I want to match with `Name` and put those values in 1st column and `Admin` on 2nd column followed by `Oper` in 3rd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format data into a table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649799/format-data-into-a-table)

Comment: Can the `Name>...` record be missing at times or does it systematically appear at regular interval in the data to be processed ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to

- collapse multi-line records into single CSV lines,
- only print the values of the record attributes `Name`, `Admin` and `Oper`
- and print "explicit" empty fields where one of these attributes is not given.

I would recommend the following `awk` program:

```
awk -F'>' 'function printrec(){printf "%s,%s,%s\n",buf["Name"],buf["Admin"],buf["Oper"]}
           (FNR>1 && $1=="Name"){printrec();delete buf}
           {sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"",$2); buf[$1]=$2}
           END{printrec()}' input.txt
```

It works as follows:

- The field separator for the input file is set to `>`.
- All elements of the records are stored in an associative array `buf`.
- A function `printrec()` is defined which prints the relevant fields of `buf` with comma-separation. If `buf` doesn't contain a particular key, referencing it will evaluate to the empty string, thereby fulfilling your requirement of an empty field for a missing attribute.
- A record is assumed to start with a `Name` line. If such a line is encountered, and it is *not* the first line in the file (`FNR>1`), the previously buffered record will be printed, and the buffer cleared again.
- For each line, the current attribute will be stored in `buf`, with the "key" part as "array index" and the "value" part as array value.

  **Note** that I included a `sub()` call to remove trailing space from the "value" part, which your input example contains. If you are sure that there are no spaces in reality, you can omit that part of line 3.
- At end-of-file, the final buffered record will be printed.

Applying this program to your example will yield

```
Ami,2,1
Sum,3,
Tar,1,2
```

**Note** that the use of `delete` for an array requires GNU `awk`. If you have a different `awk` flavor, you will need to use

```
split("",buf)
```

as a workaround.

Also, if a record contains multiple instances of an attribute (except for `Name` which is always taken as record start), later occurences will overwrite previous occurences.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want then you should use `xargs` and `awk` commands:

```bash
xargs -n3 < your_file.txt  | awk  '{gsub(/(Name|Admin|Oper)>/,"");  print $1","$2","$3}' | awk -F',' --file script.awk
```

Where `script.awk` contains this:

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk

{
   if($1 ~ ".*>.*") print ","$2","$3 
   else if($2 ~ ".*>.*") print $1",,"$3 
   else if($3 ~ ".*>.*") print $1","$2"," 
   else print
}
```

If in the `your_file.txt` you have:

```
Name>Ami  
Admin>2  
Oper>1  
Name>Sum  
Admin>3  
Total>2  
Name>Tar  
Admin>1  
Oper>2
```

With `xargs -n3` you will get the output of the file  every 3 lines (as one line):

```
Name>Ami Admin>2 Oper>1
Name>Sum Admin>3 Total>2
Name>Tar Admin>1 Oper>2
```

With `awk  '{gsub(/(Name|Admin|Oper)>/,"");  print $1","$2","$3}'` the values like *Name> Admin> or Oper>* will be replaced by an empty string and with `print $1","$2","$3` the values (after >) will be printed with a comma.

If you use:

```bash
xargs -n3 < data3  | awk  '{gsub(/(Name|Admin|Oper)>/,"");  print $1","$2","$3}
```

you will get:

```
Ami,2,1
Sum,3,Total>2
Tar,1,2
```

Now, it will be removed unnecessary strings like `Total>2`. With the `script.awk` you can remove them but before we have to define the separator, in this case the comma (`,`).
The awk code like `$1 ~ ".*>.*"` will verify if the current string ($1, $2 or $3) does match with the pattern `.*>.*` if it does, then, the current string will not be printed.

**Important:** The `script.awk`works by group. So, if there is a not valid column, this one must be placed instead of **Name** or **Admin** or **Oper**. For example if `your_file.txt` has:

```
Name>Ami  
Total>2  
Oper>1  
Name>Sum  
Admin>3  
Total>2  
Total>Tar  
Admin>1  
Oper>2
```

The output of the script will be:

```
Ami,,1
Sum,3,
,1,2
```

But if you have inside the `your_file.txt`:

```
Total>Ami  
Total>2  
Oper>1  
Name>Sum  
Admin>3  
Total>2  
Total>Tar  
Admin>1  
Total>2
```

the command will not work as you expect.

**Note:** If you want that `your_file.txt` be edited too, you will have to use `tee your_file.txt` at the end:

```bash
xargs -n3 < your_file.txt  | awk  '{gsub(/(Name|Admin|Oper)>/,"");  print $1","$2","$3}' | awk -F',' --file script.awk | tee your_file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Edgar, Even the paste will do the same but let say we have any different value in between(lets say 'Total>3) it will take this value as well. which needs to be avoided as the table only has Name,Admin and Oper.

Comment: Ok! I'll try to edit the answer to provide a better solution (using `grep`  perhaps)

Comment: Thanks Edgar!! Really Appreciate your help in this but this will again fail if we have any missing column. Let say we don't have Oper present in some case it will fail:

Comment: @amit10504 oh, I thought there was no problem for that issue.
Can you edit your question to provide that information?  And for example, if the file doesn't have any missing column the script should fail (and edit nothing)?

Comment: @amit10504 the command should fail if there are repeat values, should not? For example: `Name>Ami,Name>Sum` or `Name>Ami,Admin>1,Name>Sum` it should fail perhaps.

Comment: I have made the changes in my Question for better understanding

Comment: @amit10504 ok! I'll try to answer again :D

Answer (score 0):

*[Not knowing whether the `Name>...` record can be missing at times instead of systematically appearing at regular interval in the data to be processed, I will assume it's always there.]*

A simple solution based on awk:

- does not use an intermediate array,
- need not resort to defining a function:
- fixes the issue of trailing spaces in the data records to process
- allows for any number of input files listed as space separated arguments of the `awk` script below.

and is, subjectively, a little simpler to read, although perhaps less elegant than @AdminBee's answer.

```
 $ awk -F'>' '($1 == "Name") {
                  if (NR>1) printf "\n"; 
                  gsub(" ","",$2); 
                  printf "%s%s", $2,","}
              ($1 == "Admin") {
                  gsub(" ","",$2); 
                  printf "%s%s", $2,","} 
              ($1 == "Oper") {
                  gsub(" ","",$2); 
                  printf "%s", $2} 
              END {printf "\n"}' input_file
Ami,2,1
Sum,3,
Tar,1,2
```

In the above, action `gsub(" ","",$2)` suppresses all spaces in the second field, denoted `$2`. (OP includes those trailing spaces and they wreak havoc when displaying results.)

Answer (score 0):

If only the input data looked a bit more like this (rec-formatted):

```
Name: Ami
Admin: 2
Oper: 1

Name: Sum
Admin: 3
Total: 2

Name: Tar
Admin: 1
Oper: 2
```

... then we could easily use `rec2csv | csvcut -C Total` to produce the CSV document

```
Name,Admin,Oper
Ami,2,1
Sum,3,
Tar,1,2
```

Here `rec2csv` is a utility from GNU recutils that reformats rec-formatted data into CSV, and `csvcut` is a utility that selects columns from CSV (here it's used to *exclude* the `Total` column), from csvkit.

The original data can be transformed into rec-formatted format using `awk`, and then fed into `rec2csv` and `csvcut`:

```bash
awk '/^Name>/ { print "" } { sub(">",": "); print }' file | rec2csv | csvcut -C Total
```

This simply ensures that each line that starts with `Name>` is preceded by an empty line and then replaces the first occurrence of `>` with `:`  on each line.

Pass the result through `tail -n +2` if you want to remove the CSV header.

This obviously assumes that each occurrence of `Name>` in the original file introduces a new record.

---

If only the input looked a bit more like this (xtab-formatted):

```
Name Ami
Admin 2
Oper 1

Name Sum
Admin 3
Total 2

Name Tar
Admin 1
Oper 2
```

Then we could use `mlr` (Miller) to first "unsparsify" each record (assign empty values to missing keys), and then extract the wanted keys in CSV output format:

```bash
mlr --ixtab unsparsify | mlr --ocsv cut -f Name,Admin,Total
```

We can get the original data into xtab-format using an `awk` command similar to the previous one, and then feed it through Miller:

```bash
awk '/^Name>/ { print "" } { sub(">"," "); print }' file | mlr --ixtab unsparsify | mlr --ocsv cut -f Name,Admin,Oper
```

This would give you

```
Name,Admin,Oper
Ami,2,1
Sum,3,
Tar,1,2
```

Use `mlr` (the final one in the pipeline) with its `-N` option to remove the CSV header.